# I am receiving a "Network Error: Unable to reach the server" error when I try to edit a contact via "edit address" button

Tags: contacts

When I use the "Show Javascript" console, the following error line has appeared: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)" followed by this url: "http://www.domainname.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fajax%2Finline"

Running CiviCRM 5.17.3 via Wordpress

ConfigAndLog reveals nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Given that it's a 403 error, I would check to see if WordFence (or similar "security" plugin for WordPress) is the cause by temporarily disabling it (ideally on a test site).  If you're using Apache, it may be a rogue .htaccess file causing the problem.